# Multiple Tasks slows down

Tags: c#, multithreading

The code:

```
static void DoIt(string name)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello {0} | {1}", name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadID);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Bye {0} | {1}", name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadID);
}

static void Main()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt("One"));
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt("Two"));
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt("Three"));
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt("Four"));
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt("Five"));
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt("Six"));
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt("Seven"));
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt("Eight"));
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt("Nine"));
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt("Ten"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

How come that it can fine start the first 3 Tasks immediately, but then it takes 5-10sec for Task 4 to start, and after Task 4 have started, then it takes 5-10sec before Task 5 starts and so on. Is it the GC thats doing something? Could someone please clarify whats happening?

Comment: how many cores do you think your CPU has? it's not a detail in this case... :)

Comment: I saw the same behavior in a heavily network IO bound application that kicked off 100 tasks.  The 100 tasks were actually needed to get close to maximum system throughput, but later tasks took a long time to start.

Comment: @Davide: Do you KNOW that TPL is assuming the tasks are CPU bound or just assuming that?  It would be nice to know if that is the case.

Comment: I don't know anything... I am guessing. :) in my guess creating a number of concurrent operations with lower number of executing units (cores) can only imply slower overall execution than doing things one after the other, if nothing else at least some overhead for the context switches or the scheduling. Not an expert of TPL here anyway.

Comment: Do you have an AMD 3 core machine?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How come that it can fine start the first 3 Tasks immediately, but then it takes 5-10sec for Task 4 to start, and after Task 4 have started, then it takes 5-10sec before Task 5 starts and so on. Is it the GC thats doing something? Could someone please clarify whats happening?

By default, the first time you run this, the `ThreadPool` is allocated using the minimum number of worker threads.  After the first 4 tasks are scheduled, the threadpool will "ramp up" to handle more over time, which is why you see the delay.

On my system (which has 8 cores), the first 8 are instantanteous, then the next two start up one second later.

In your case, if you run your test two times, the **second** time, the threads will all start up immediately.  This is because, after the first run, the ThreadPool should have enough workers to schedule this right away.

Try the following to see this behavior in action.  If you leave the SetMinThreads call in place, these will all schedule immediately.  If you comment it out, you'll see that, the first time, it takes a while, but the second time through (provided you wait for the threads to complete), the threads will run immediately.

```
static void DoIt(string name)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello {0} | {1} - {2}", name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Bye {0} | {1} - {2}", name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now);
}

static void Main()
{
    int workerThreads, complete;
    ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out workerThreads, out complete);

    Console.WriteLine(workerThreads);

    // Comment out this line to see the difference...
    // WIth this commented out, the second iteration will be immediate
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, complete);

    Action run = () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
            {
                int tmp = i;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt(tmp.ToString()));
            }
        };

    run();
    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to run again...");
    Console.ReadKey();

    run();

    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note that this behavior actually has little to do with the TPL as a whole - it's more the default `TaskScheduler` used which just passes off the tasks to the `ThreadPool`.  If you were to set these threads up with the `LongRunning` hint in your `StartNew()` call, for example, they'd all start immediately (since the default scheduler will setup a new, dedicated thread and execute it immediately).

Comment: Thanks for the very detailing answer! - If I comment out `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, complete)`, and run it twice, then it wont immediately start ALL of the tasks second time, but only the first 15-17. Whats happening to the others?

Comment: @ebb: Depending on how long you take between clicks, the ThreadPool will start to shut down threads (back to the Min...)  The longer you wait, the fewer will start up immediately.

Answer (score 6):

The tasks aren't slowing down, they're being queued by the Task Parallel Library. The CLR knows how many logical cores are available on your computer; <s>TPL</s> the thread pool uses this information to determine how many worker threads to make available. In your case, you probably have four logical cores; taking one away for the main thread (on which `Main()` is running) three cores (and three thread pool workers) remain to execute tasks.

Comment: Just FYI - This is actually the `ThreadPool` that is making this determination in this case, not the TPL...

Comment: You are indeed correct; I've edited my answer to be a little more precise.

Comment: BTW - I suspect this is a 3 core machine - The UI/Main thread is typically not a ThreadPool thread, so the fact that the OP is only getting 3 tasks suggests they probably have something like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Phenom#Phenom_X3

Comment: While you may be correct (I certainly don't know off the top of my head) I thought the thread pool accounted for at least one previously-running thread within the process.

Comment: Nope - It does 1 worker thread per core for the min threads, at the start.  (You can see this in my test code below, if you're interested...)   Doesn't change much, but is interesting to know.  Without this, a single core system would have no worker threads, so the first call to ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem would take quite a while...

Comment: Well played, sir. That makes more sense than I cared to consider. :)

Answer (score 0):

The TPL contains very sophisticated algorithms which adapt to the workload.  What you are experiencing sounds about right for a 4-core machine -- the TPL has decided to do something that it thinks is beneficial in a situation where so many threads are created.