# Too many tasks slow down the UI Thread

Tags: c#, .net, task

What can I do so that background Tasks have a lower priority than the UI thread?

I have a list of items for each of which some data is calculated in the background. I use Tasks for each calculation so the UI Thread is not affeted.

However, I realized that if I have a lot of items (> 50), the UI Thread gets affected nevertheless. (The list does not scroll smoothly, for example)

It seems that the big amount of Tasks take away CPU time from the UI thread.

(I don't want to change from Tasks to Threads because Tasks are so handy. There must be a way!)

Comment: Please show some code, preferrably a minimal example showing the undesired behaivour.

Comment: If it turns out too many threads are being spawned, you can use a [custom task scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351) to limit the number of threads.

Comment: see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393938/multiple-tasks-slows-down

Comment: Are the background threads passing a lot of information back to the GUI thread via Invoke/BeginInvoke?

Comment: Do you really need a task for each item or cant you just make a task handle more than one?

Comment: @adv12: Good point. But it was not the reason.

Comment: @CSharpie: Would be possible. But then I would have to rewrite a lot of code.

Comment: @mbeckish: You have lead me to the right way: I managed it not with limited thread number but with decreased priority. 
It's a WinRT app, so the normal ThreadPool is not available. But there is Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool which has a RunAsync() method with priority parameter. This works. The only problem is that the task is started immediately (which I do not want actually). 
Another solution is to use this TaskScheduler: http://steffenzeidler.blogspot.de/2013/01/net-priority-task-scheduler.html
But I don't know if it is bug free. Any official solution? (Make your post as answer!)

Comment: @eikuh - The solution I like to use is to implement my own [Producer/Consumer queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) based off of ideas in [Joseph Albahari's Threading post](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).  That way, you can explicitly control how many threads are used, delay/pause/cancel execution, etc.